# Why does my caret not return to the beginning of a TRichViewEdit?

Tags: delphi, caret

I'm using a TRichViewEdit for a chat application and after sending the text in the Edit I clear it. The problem is after I clear the Edit the caret appears at the end of the last item. If I click on the Edit or start typing again, the caret returns to the beginning. Why is it not moving back right away?

I've tried calling `RichViewEdit.Update` and `.SelectWordAt(0,0)` and neither of those seems to work.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Retuerns to the beginning of what? You just cleared where it was at, it needs to go somewhere (end of last item), and it isn't going to go anywhere else until it's told to..

Comment: If you've just cleared the text, what "last item" are you talking about? Note that you can move the caret wherever you want by assigning the `SelPos` property, if this control is like other `TCustomEdit` descendants.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson The caret should be at the beginning of the RichEdit when `.Clear` is called. @RobKennedy I know there are no items since it's been cleared, but the caret appears (blinking of course) where the end of the last item was. Also, it doesn't have a `SelPos` property because it's a TRichViewEdit.

Comment: Ah now I get you. What version of delphi and what version of windows. Looks like a classic windows message problem in the VCL wrapper component.

Answer (score 2):

So I found a workaround by calling `RVEdit.SetSelectionBounds(0,0,0,0)` after the clear, it moves the caret back to the beginning of the edit box.

Comment: That's great, but note that you haven't actually *answered* the question. You didn't ask how you could *work around* the problem. You asked *why* the problem occurs at all.

Comment: True, thanks for pointing that out. But I thought others might like to know how I solved the problem (at least temporarily).

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
RichViewEdit1.Clear; 
RichViewEdit1.Format;
```